# Two calendars synchronization

Tags: python, synchronization, calendar

Question is rather conceptual, then direct.
What's the best solution to keep two different calendars synchronised? I can run a cron job for example every minute, I can keep additional information in database. How to avoid events conflicts?
As far I was thinking about these two solutions. First one is keeping a database which gathers information from both calendars and each time compares if something new appeared in any of them. Inside this database we can judge, which events should be added, edited or removed and then send those information back to both calendars.
Second one is keepien two databases for both calendars and collecting information separately. Then, after those databases are compared, we can say, where did the changes occure and send information from database A to calendar B or from database B to calendar A. I'm afraid this solution leads to more conflicts when changes were made to both databases.

What do you think of these? To be more accurate, I mean two google calendars and script written in python using gdata. Any idea of more simple solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most calendars, including the Google calendar, has ways to import and synchronize data. You can use these ways. Just import the gdata information (perhaps you need to make it into ics first, I don't know) into the Google calendar.

Comment: As I don't think, I'm really going to have any other answer's, this one gets accepted. The problem has been solved some time ago and actually the idea of importing was quite helpful.